# Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded error with useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Why am I getting this error?

```
Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**
```

This is my code:

```
const [roles, setRoles] = useState([]);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  setRoles(["5nxg5wvb"]);
});
```

Note that the same error appears when I use useEffect, and that error only goes away when I change the code to this:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  setRoles("5nxg5wvb");
});
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a dependency array in `setEffect` or it will run on [every state change](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#detailed-explanation).  Since it's changing state, that means it will run, which causes it to run again, which causes it to run again, etc...

The dependency array tells it *when* to run.  An empty array means "run this effect on mount," so it will run only once.  An array with variable names in it means, "run when any of these variables change."

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  setRoles("5nxg5wvb");
}, []);
```

Comment: Of course! Stupid mistake on my side... Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Why did this error occur?

Because you are using `useEffect` or `useLayoutEffect` while you don't specify the second params of the hooks, you only put the first param which is the callback function, and the state value is always different.

#### Why does putting this `["5nxg5wvb"]` doesn't work while putting `"5nxg5wvb"` works?

1. Because if you use `[]` (an array), you create a new object and compare it with the previous object every time it re-renders (because you don't specify the second params of the hooks, but do know that `[] === []` will result in `false` value)
2. While if you use `""` (a string), React will directly compare the value instead, and if it's the same, the state won't be updated and there will be no re-rendering.

---

#### How to fix this?

1. You can put the second param of the hooks like this, the code below will make the hooks run only once:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  setRoles(["5nxg5wvb"]);
}, []);
```

2. Just put the new value directly to the `useState` like this, there is no need to put `useEffect` with static data:

```
const [roles, setRoles] = useState(["5nxg5wvb"]);
```

---

If both suggestions don't work for your use case, please do put more info about your use case.